# Reverse/"Time Traveling" Debuggers for Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

There are several reverse debuggers for Java, .NET, C, and C++.  Unless you count scattered references to using GDB with Javascript, I can't find any practical implementations. Is there a reason I cannot hookup GB in Eclipse or Intellij with Javascript?

Comment: JavaScript is not compiled in any traditional way. The code is interpreted in a virtual machine.

Comment: What's a reverse debugger?

Comment: @DaveNewton hit a breakpoint and go backwards ... I've never used one

Comment: @Pointy Oh, time travel, I understand now. I didn't even know they were called that, shows how much I know-I guess going up stack frames has always been enough for me, although to be honest, it's rare I step through code.

Comment: I don't quite understand what this is, but among other things it has a time traveling debugger: https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Answer (score 3):

[This video](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/Marron/Time-Travel-Debugging-for-JavaScriptHTML) from Microsoft Research describes an experimental time-traveling debugger inside the next-generation Microsoft Edge web browser (as of May 2015, it is not public yet)

excerpt from John Vilk:

> *(it is a) new approach called interrogative virtualization whose primary goal is to efficiently capture application-level semantics in order to minimize the size of VM snapshots and event logs. By raising the abstraction level of the VMI to that of the application of interest, interrogative VMs can safely ignore large portions of architectural state in the OS and the hardware. As a concrete demonstration, we introduce JavaScript virtual machines ...*
>
> > *To demonstrate the utility of interrogative VMIs, we build MoveJS, a system that efficiently migrates the client-side of web applications across physical machines, and **ReJS, a time-travel debugger for the browser.***
> >
> > *This work is currently in submission.*

Comment: This looks great, I wonder about its progress now, given the video was posted in May 2015. Would be great to see this implemented in chrome